# How can sorting objects into buckets be formulated as valid JPQL expression?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I would like to display a 2D-chart containing the amount of processed objects (mapped in JPA) in a given time span. This amount can be scale up to around 30k objects in an timespan of 30 minutes.

As a DBMS I am using PostgreSQL 9.4 and JPA 2.0 with Hibernate in version 4.2.21.

At the moment I am using this piece of code in order to add the amount into my temporal "buckets".

```
 // Get all objects after a given start date
List<MyObject> myObjects= myJPADbService.getMyObjects(Date.from(startDate.atZone
            (ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()), Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (MyObject information : myObjects) {
        LocalDateTime pageDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(information.getLastSeen().getTime()), ZoneId.systemDefault());          
    long duration;
    if (temporalUnit == ChronoUnit.MINUTES) {
     duration = Duration.between(startDate, pageDate).toMinutes();
    } else if (temporalUnit == ChronoUnit.DAYS) {
     duration = Duration.between(startDate, pageDate).toDays();
    } else {
     duration = Duration.between(startDate, pageDate).toHours();
   }

  pagesPerUnit[(int) (Math.abs(duration))]++;
}
```

However depending on an user selected timespan, this piece of code might be very inefficient. It might be more efficient, if the DBMS computes the buckets according to an user selected timespan.

How can this be formulated in proper JPQL syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need a JPA way of computing the difference between the `startDate` and `pageDate` in the respective unit, which is somewhat hard to formulate because it's very database dependent. In the end you will need some custom functions or write a very complicated JPQL query.

Computing the days between two dates in PostgreSQL is as easy as doing `date_part('day', t2 - t1)`. For the hours you already need `date_part('day', t2 - t1) * 24 + date_part('hour', t2 - t1)` and minutes `date_part('day', t2 - t1) * 24 * 60 + date_part('hour', t2 - t1) * 60 + date_part('minute', t2 - t1)`.

In order to use these database functions in JPQL, you can use the `FUNCTION` syntax like `FUNCTION('date_part', 'day', :startDate - pageDate)`.

In the end, you will be grouping by such an expression and do a count by id, something like the following

`SELECT COUNT(o.id)
FROM MyObject o
GROUP BY FUNCTION('date_part', 'day', :startDate - o.pageDate)`