# Difference in executing query via Hibernate and PostgreSQL leading to PSQLException

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I would like to execute a native SQL query via JPA 2.0 with Hibernate in version 4.2.21 on a Postgres 9.4 database system.

Basically, according to my latest [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060883/how-can-sorting-objects-into-buckets-be-formulated-as-valid-jpql-expression) on stackoverflow, I try to put a large number of objects/records into "temporal" buckets.

The setup can be simplified to the following setup containing a table "MyObject" with an id field and a given timestamp:

```
CREATE TABLE myobject
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  lastseen timestamp without time zone, 
)
```

My piece of code, which should execute the query is this one:

```
Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(
             "select count(id),date_part('day', :startDate - c.lastseen)  AS " +
             "difference from myobject c " +
             "group by date_part('day', :startDate - c.lastseen) order by difference asc");

q.setParameter("startDate", startDate);

List<Object[]> rawResults = q.getResultList();

//process the reuslts
```

Executing this query with a sample date via **pgAdmin3** returns the result as expected.

However, if I try to execute the same query via Hibernate as a native query it fails with the following exception:

> ```
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
> FEHLER: column „myobject.lastseen“ must appear in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   Position: 40
>   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
>   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
>   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:305)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
>   ... 94 more
> ```

This exception seems valid and self-explaining but why can I execute the same query via **PgAdmin3**? Is the Hibernate SQL parser more strict than **pgAdmin3** or does it compensate some mistake?

So how can my SQL query be formulated in order to make it executable via Hibernate?

**EDIT:**

For some reason the following SQL statement (with explicit sub-select) works via PgAdmin3 as well as via Hibernate:

```
select count(id), difference
from (select c.id,c.lastseen,date_part('day', :startDate - c.lastseen) AS difference
      from myobject c) AS temporalBucket
group by difference
order by difference asc
```

But this still does not answer the question for the previous query in the given code fragment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query should work as well, without subquery:

```sql
SELECT count(id)  -- or even better: count(*) AS ct
     , date_part('day', :startDate - c.lastseen) AS difference
FROM   myobject c 
GROUP  BY difference
ORDER  BY difference;
```

The reason I suspect: Hibernate uses [prepared statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQPREPARE) and the two occurrences of `:startDate` are passed as *two* parameters. This way, Postgres cannot assume that both expressions (in the `SELECT` list and in `GROUP BY`) are the same ...

Demonstrating with the equivalent [SQL command `PREPARE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html), this works:

```sql
PREPARE test1 AS
SELECT count(*) AS ct
     , date_part('day', $1 - c.lastseen) AS difference
FROM   myobject c 
GROUP  BY date_part('day', $1 - c.lastseen)
ORDER  BY difference;
```

While this does not:

```sql
PREPARE test2 AS
SELECT count(*) AS ct
     , date_part('day', $1 - c.lastseen) AS difference
FROM   myobject c 
GROUP  BY date_part('day', $2 - c.lastseen)
ORDER  BY difference;
```

.. and raises the same exception as you show.

You can avoid the problem a priori with the query I suggested.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL Where count condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119489/postgresql-where-count-condition/8119815#8119815)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Great answer!